# How to manage a project folder via ssh?

Tags: ssh, visual-studio-code, development-environment

Developing full-stack web apps, I would like to have all my code and build logic on a linux machine (i.e. git, docker containers and other terminal commands), but all my development workflow on my windows machine (so my IDE, web browser and REST client) accessing it via SSH.

I've managed to do all of that except for the IDE, I could only edit individual files via SSH instead of managing a folder as a project. So right now I use VSCode on the linux machine (Ubuntu), and it's the last thing preventing me for dropping the graphical interface and install Ubuntu Server on it.

And no, I don't want to use Vim or Emacs. I want to use VSCode, or another modern IDE, but preferably VSCode.

Comment: You cannot use VSCode without a desktop environment

Comment: That's not the point. The point is using it on Windows via ssh ... please read the question more carefully.

Comment: Sorry, now I am understanding your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the Remote VSCode plugin as explained here: [Using Remote VSCode](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2017/12/18/remote-vscode-file-editing/)

This discussion is exactly about your problem: [VSCode 13643 issue Github](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/13643)

EDIT: I have recently found a new VSCode plugin on Github: [vs-deploy](https://github.com/mkloubert/vs-deploy). It was designed to deploy files and folders remotely very quickly. It seems to be working and I haven't found any bugs so far. It works with FTP, SFTP (SSH) and many other protocols.

Comment: That's what I did, this only supports files, not projects (folders).

Comment: Ok, use multiple tabs as explained

Answer (score 0):

The [SSH.NET nuget Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SSH.NET) can be used quite nicly to copy files and folders.
Here is an example:

```
var host = "YourServerIpAddress";
var port = 22;
var user = "root"; // TODO: fix
var yourPathToAPrivateKeyFile = @"C:\Users\Bob\mykey"; // Use certificate for login
var authMethod = new PrivateKeyAuthenticationMethod(user, new PrivateKeyFile(yourPathToAPrivateKeyFile));
var connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo(host, port, user, authMethod);
using (var client = new SftpClient(connectionInfo))
{
    client.Connect();
    if (client.IsConnected)
    {
        //TODO: Copy folders recursivly etc.
        DirectoryInfo source = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\your\probject\publish\path");
        foreach (var file in source.GetFiles())
        {
            client.UploadFile(File.OpenRead(file.FullName), $"/home/yourUploadPath/{file.Name}", true);
        }
    }
}
```

When you create a upload console application using the code above your should be able to automatically trigger an upload by using postbuild events by adding a section to your Project.

```
<Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent">
    <Exec Command="path to execute your script or application" />
</Target>
```

If you prefer to do the same but more manual you can perform a

```
dotnet build --configuration Release
```

followed by a

```
dotnet publish ~/projects/app1/app1.csproj
```

and then use the code above to perform an upload.

Answer (score 0):

Search for the extension SSHExtension developed by Vitaly Kondratiev
Install the extension.
And edit the serverlist json with the server details. 
ex:
"sshextension.serverList": [
        {
            "name": "Kuberntes 212",
            "host": "10.64.234.54",
            "port": 22,
            "username": "root",
            "password": "byebye"
        }
]
save the file

Then log in using ctrl+shift+p and choose sshextension open ssh extension category. It shall create a session for you.

More Easily if u need the entire directory structure into ur local workspace.
Use extension ftp-simple in vscode. It works as a wonder, trust me.
Install ftp-simple in vscode 
ctrl+shift+p
select ftp-simple:config.
Configure your settings 
[
    {
        "name": "Kubernetes 212",
        "host": "10.75.64.2",
        "port": 22,
        "type": "sftp",
        "username": "root",
        "password": "byebye",
        "path": "/home/vinod/",
        "autosave": true,
        "confirm": true
    }]
save the file.
Now ctrl+shift+p
and select ftp-simple:remote directory to workspace.

Viola Your work is done, Life is simple